# How can I randonly select rows after grouping by a column?

Tags: sql-server, random, group-by

Say I have the following table:

MyTable

```
id | val | val2
---------------
1  | 'a' | 1.2
1  | 'b' | 2.3
1  | 'c' | 3.4
2  | 'b' | 4.5
2  | 'c' | 5.6
2  | 'b' | 6.7
2  | 'a' | 7.8
2  | 'd' | 8.9
```

I want a query that will **randomly** return one of the rows for each unique `id`.  But the result should not "separate" the pairing between `val` and `val2`.  So

```
id | val | val2
---------------
1  | 'a' | 1.2
2  | 'b' | 4.5
```

is a valid result, but

```
id | val | val2
---------------
1  | 'a' | 1.2
2  | 'b' | 5.6
```

is not.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` and `NEWID()` for the random sorting:

```
SELECT
    id, val1, val2
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY NEWID())
    FROM tbl
)t
WHERE Rn = 1
```